# Is there a HTML code for a monthly calendar with checkboxes for everyday?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, calendar

I am looking for some help. I have a leadpages website and I am looking to add a live calendar to my website which has a checkbox on each day for my clients to tick whether they did their daily habit.

Leadpages hasn’t got a calendar function but has a custom HTML widget button which I was hoping to use to insert this calendar. I just need help with what the code would be to make something like this - would love some help with this!

Please contact me or reply if you can help me with this!

I will attach a photo of what I would like or similar!

[Calendar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5qHj.jpg)

Comment: You want one community calendar that everyone can add to, or you want to create a calendar that will be different for each user?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: https://uicookies.com/html-calendar/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've had a look at those and they look great but I'm not skilled enough to edit the code to insert checkboxes to each date, do you think you could help me in that aspect?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. Do you want a community calendar that everyone can edit, or do you want each user to be able to edit their own individual calendar?

Comment: Ideally, I would want each client to be able to edit their own individual calendar on their own webpage. As I am a habit fitness coach, I am wanting them to tick the checkbox on days they completed their habits. Thanks :)

Comment: That's going to take a lot more than whatever you could put in an HTML box, since you'll need your website to keep track of who is using it. Maybe someone out there made exactly what you want in a form that can just be embedded, but if you haven't been able to find it on Google, you probably won't find it on SO. My suggestion would be to settle for something else. You might embed a Google calendar: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en.

Comment: Oh okay I wondered that, I have already embedded the google calendar but wasn't able to find anything as simple as a checkbox in each day - is this just not a possibility for me?

Comment: For each individual user? Probably not. That's actually really complicated, since the website would have to create a different experience for each user. You can't do that in HTML alone.

Comment: Okay, even if I were to create a new calendar for each user and webpage, this still would be tricky to do?

Comment: You really have to program to get what you want. There's no simple code snippet you can use.